# Retrieving Magento certification profile from Magento api

Tags: magento

Can someone explain how can I retrieve the certification profile details of a Magento Certified Professional using Magento api?

I can get the information manually by searching at the below link:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/directory/

I looked into the api documentation but I could not find any information on how to get the certification profile information. Is it possible to get the information somehow?

Comment: There is no such api for certification details.

Comment: I can use cURL to get the public profile. Is there any limit on the number of requests that can be sent?